# Disable boolean query in Solr for edismax

Tags: solr, edismax

How do I disable boolean operators in edismax for solr?

The following query: `Edismax -The Extended DisMax Query Parser` should not exclude results mentioning "the" (given that stop words is not used).

Comment: how word the related to boolean query? could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that Solr has an option to deactivate boolean operators. (Though I could be unaware of it - Solr is *huge!*)

My standard practice is to modify user-entered queries before passing them along to Solr. If punctuation isn't relevant in your search structure anyway, you could simply remove the hyphen, replace it with a space, or if you want to preserve the structure of hyphenated terms for your Solr analyzers to play with, you might selectively replace the specific pattern `" -"` with a single space `" "`, and so leave regular hyphenated expressions alone.

If you're not sure that the hyphen is irrelevant data in your search you could replace it instead with a sentinel character or sequence of characters that will pass cleanly though your query parser and field analysis, but you would probably want to do the same thing to the input data going into the search index so the two sentinel values can match within Solr.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have not come up with any other solution my self then what you suggest.